# Ui frameworks with AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, angular, user-experience

I am designing an application in which I plan to use a good UI framework like Kendo, smart admin, etc for my application along with AngularJS.

Most of them, if I am not wrong, use some version of jQuery or jQuery UI. My understanding is that Angular with jQuery is not advised.

However Bootstrap is fine but does Bootstrap need jQuery?

I get a feeling that Angular 1x with jQuery is heavy and can be taxing on browsers/mobile alike.

What other UI framework options do I have? Please suggest.

Comment: The question is opinion-based. You have UI Bootstrap or Angular Material as Angular options. Non-Angular (jQuery) frontend code is not recommended for use with Angular because of the complications it brings, not because of extra Kbs.

Answer (score 0):

Angular actually uses jQLite by default, which can be replaced with standard jQuery just by loading jQuery first. Angular & jQuery play well together. What is not advised is to write your own jQuery style code when working with Angular and instead to approach things "the Angular way." Using Angular is not a reason to discard the entire jQuery ecosystem. You may want to take a look at this question and answer for more details: ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background?rq=1).